# AWS: How to map non-Route53 domain to CloudFront with A record

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-cloudfront

How can I set it up so that a domain which has not been registered with Route53 (since the TLD is not provided by Route53 and the domain is pre-existing) is correctly pointing to CloudFront via an A record?

Since the root entry of a domain must not be a CNAME, I'm stumped...

Comment: There is no universal solution for this problem. Your best bet is probably to switch DNS hosting to Route53 and use ALIAS record (you can do that with existing domain and it shouldn't matter where is the domain name registered)

Comment: Who is hosting your DNS?

Comment: thanks DusanBajic and hephalump for your answers - i'm gonna switch NS and it should be good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this outside of Route 53. The Route 53 DNS system has special Alias record handling that allows you to associate an A record at the domain root. You can keep the current domain at the current registrar. And only change the name servers registered there to Route 53.